# Transform Along Z in 'View' Transform Orientation

Tags: python, scripting

If the transform orientation is set to 'View', no transform along Z axis should possible, since the view is always 2d. But in perspective view, the transformation along Z is still possible (which makes sense because it's perspective view).

[image]

Any idea, how this transformation can be calculated using python (transform along X and Y can be calculated using region_3d.view_matrix, but this fails with Z)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'fails with Z' (and not x y) using view_matrix?

Comment: After applying the view_matrix the X and Y values are correct but Z does not change, i. e. it changes in global space in such a way that there is no movement along Z in view.

Comment: I'm guessing here: these view matrices should be orthogonal (I think) so try calculating the Z axis as the cross product between the X and Y.